# Find groups in dataframe missing certain subgroups and append that subgroup

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a list of several hundred 'providers' and the monthly counts of each of (UP TO) 4 admission reasons. It looks a bit like this:

```
Provider|AdmsnRsn|102012Count|112012Count|...|092014Count
10001   |1       |19         |33         |...|29
10001   |2       |103        |109        |...|66
10001   |3       |59         |44         |...|24
10001   |M       |166        |174        |...|233
10007   |2       |0          |0          |...|21
10007   |3       |0          |0          |...|45
10007   |M       |0          |0          |...|32
10009   |2       |47         |55         |...|39
10012   |1       |109        |107        |...|113
```

I need to insert an 'M' for AdmsnRsn for all providers WITHOUT one, and insert 0 for all monthly counts in that row (row should be inserted at last row for that provider). I don't really know where to start with this. I know how to subset data frames, but I can't find a source that shows information on how to subset where a subgroup is missing a certain value. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code to insert "M" for `AdmsRsn` and "0" for `XXXCount` columns for `Providers` without one. May be not the best method but works.

**R Code**

```
Data <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Manohar\\Desktop\\Data.csv", sep=",", header=T)

View(Data)
#   Provider    AdmsRsn X102012Count    X112012Count    X092014Count
#1  10001       1                 19              33              29
#2  10001       2                 103            109              66
#3  10001       3                 59              44              24
#4  10001       M                166             174             233
#5  10007       2                  0               0              21
#6  10007       3                  0               0              45
#7  10007       M                  0               0              32
#8  10009       2                 47              55              39
#9  10012       1                109             107             113

# Providers having 1
ProviderOnes <- unique(Data[Data$AdmsRsn == 1,1])
ProviderOnes
# [1] 10001 10012

# Providers not having one
ProviderMissingOnes <- unique(Data[!Data$Provider %in% ProviderOnes,1])
ProviderMissingOnes
# [1] 10007 10009

DF <- lapply(ProviderMissingOnes, function(x) {rbind(c(x,"M",rep(0,ncol(Data)-2)))})
DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(DF), nrow=length(ProviderMissingOnes), byrow=T))
colnames(DF) <- colnames(Data)
Data <- rbind(Data, DF)

# Sort the data frame, row number 8 and 10 are the newly added records
Data <- Data[order(Data$Provider, decreasing = FALSE),]
View(Data)
#   Provider    AdmsRsn X102012Count    X112012Count    X092014Count
#1  10001       1                 19              33              29
#2  10001       2                 103            109              66
#3  10001       3                 59              44              24
#4  10001       M                166             174             233
#5  10007       2                  0               0              21
#6  10007       3                  0               0              45
#7  10007       M                  0               0              32
#8  10007       M                  0               0               0
#9  10009       2                 47              55              39
#10 10009       M                  0               0               0
#11 10012       1                109             107             113
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to quite work - for instance 10007 already has an M but is given another, and 10012 *doesn't* have an M but isn't given one. I will read through and see what I can learn from your answer though. Thanks!

Comment: quoting from your question, `insert an 'M' for AdmsnRsn for all providers WITHOUT one`. 10007 does not have 1 so inserted new row with "M" and 10012 has 1 so did not insert. I guess you'll have to rephrase your question! Correct me if I'm wrong, you are looking to add "M" for providers without 1 only if its missing and also those providers that do not have "M"?

Comment: Ah, I meant insert an 'M' for providers without an 'M'. I think I just replace    `ProviderOnes <- unique(Data[Data$AdmsRsn == 1,1])` with     `ProviderOnes <- unique(Data[Data$AdmsRsn == 'M',1])` , correct?